# Desktop distributed application architecture

Tags: .net, architecture, distributed, ignite, application-design

I've got some .NET application that's pretty old (requires a lot of support) and I'm going to replace it for a new one. The application has some critical features:

- After external API synchronization, it has to have an ability to work offline and after going online again, it has to synchronize with external API.
- It has to synchronize state between devices in local network (app realizes some kind of transactions, with virtual cash)
- Performance and app responsibility is important

Current application architecture looks like:

[image: Current application architecture]

- We've got eg. 3 identical devices (D1,D2,D3)
- One device called "master" (D1) is responsible for external API data synchronization.
- Other devices (D2,D3) uses database stored on D1 device

...and everything works just great - but only in "good" environments.

**- Most problematic thing is that even, if client want to use only one device eg. D2, he has to also turn on D1.
 - Another thing is that when D1 is down, they we loose everything (because of devices are not very good quality, it's very common problem)**

My client's are not an IT "specialists", and they just can't understand which one is "master" and why they have to turn on another device despite the fact that they want to use JUST ONE device (whoever had contact with the support line knows what I'm talking about ;) )

So, my idea was to make everything easier for the client (and also for me). I thought that such an architecture may help:

[image: architecture idea]

- Every application may become "master" (still only one in the whole network) and do an API sync
- Data is replicated to every device in real time (I'm thinking about usage of Apache Ignite, but have no idea if it's not an overkill)

And i see few pros:

- No "masters", no "slaves"
- Data redundancy (in the application case, security is more important than storage)
- Synchronization without one centralized server

But also I can see one big cons - in situation when client use eg. only D1 for some time (without running any other device), and then he run only D2, data will not be synchronized (obviously ;) ).
To fix that problem, I think we're able to synchronize last turned off device state with external API on application exit (but i really don't know if it's a good idea).

And there's my question, what do you think about my idea? Maybe there are another cons (or pros?) i cant see? Or maybe you've got another idea to solve current's architecture problems ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any advice on the overall architecture, but I'll try to list pros and cons of using Apache Ignite in this scenario.

**Pros:**

- Ignite will solve your replication task very easily, literally ~10 lines of code. Just run it in every application, it will discover other running instances and sync with them, or work on it's own if there are no other instances.
- Persistence to disk is automatic
- High-performance binary serialization is built in, so you don't have to worry about that either.

**Cons:**

- Ignite is relatively resource-hungry. You'll need at least ~300Mb of RAM initially, plus the size of your data, plus some overhead depending on data format.
- Startup and discovery of other instances can take 3-10 seconds depending on hardware

Overall, I would give it a go and see how it works for you, since it won't take much time to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So probably I'm goig to do some POC using Ignie. The only thing that puzzles me, is if it's possible to synchronize some parts of local data (local nodes located in client's network)  with some node hosted by me on the server ? It would solve my problem with separately running devices.

Comment: How are you planning to query Ignite data - key/val or SQL? Why can’t you have one Ignite cluster and one DB (different data centers, networks)?